# iphone - how the file system responds to accessing the same file at the same time?

Tags: iphone

Suppose two asynchronous operations try to read or write in the same file on a given folder. How does iOS deals with that? Is the operations queued? The app crashes? the file get corrupted?

In case it is up to the programmer to deal with this, where do I find informations or an example on how to deal with race conditions, queues, etc.?

Can you guys give me a hint?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I think that when trying to acquire the file descriptor for your file, it should fail if it is already in use.</s>

As there is apparently no way to know if the file is already opened, there might be a way to lock a file.

Links that may help you:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/Introduction.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/FileSystem/FileSystem.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Glossary/Glossary.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFFileDescriptorRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Uh, what's your basis for thinking "it should fail"?

Comment: Because I can't remember and can't try right now if you can open a read-write access to a file while it is already by another program. And having the error message "could not open file ..., the file is maybe in use by another program" is quite common nowadays. So I am pretty sure that when you try to get a file descriptor on an already opened file, the function returns an error code.

Comment: are you want to process the funcation on backend then do this like i create table and in backend phone come from webservice  and when it finish show on tableview   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadImagesInBackground:) toTarget:self withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];

Comment: @Julio Sorry, that's just not correct. NSFileHandles (or the underlying BSD file descriptors) do not include any automatic built-in write locking; you can happily open multiple write descriptors to the same file without getting an error.

Comment: Exact. Sorry about that. So that's an interesting problem :)

Comment: @David: exactly and that was my problem, because the same file was being accessed by the file system for read and write and the application was getting wrong data. I suspected that because the app run fine on simulator but crappy on the device, with wrong results. So I supposed the File System on the computer is faster, because the machine is faster and the file accesses were unlikely to happen at the same time, but on iPad there was a half second window between accesses and all accesses during this window would result in wrong data. Pretty exoteric. I took 3 days to figure and solve that.

Comment: For completeness: There **is** a file locking mechanism available at the filesystem level, but (a) it requires you to drop down to the BSD level (O_EXCL flag on `open()`), and (b) it's an "advisory" locking mechanism, so it only works if all places that are opening the file are playing by the rules. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337761/cross-user-and-cross-process-shared-settings Using a queue or NSLock within your your program is a better solution (access from other processes is a moot point on iOS, given that other apps can't get into your sandbox anyway).

Answer (score 1):

The most likely answer is "the file gets corrupted". The OS will not do anything to prevent multiple threads from writing to a file simultaneously, and if they're writing to overlapping sections of the file, all bets are off.

So, your best bet is to enforce your own queueing on access to the file. There are lots of ways to to that. At a low level, you can use an `NSLock` to prevent simultaneous access, or you might want to use a Dispatch Queue. The [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Glossary/Glossary.html) mentioned by Julio's answer is a good reference.